# Bijective function problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given function
$$F(x,y)=\frac{(x+y-2)(x+y-1)}{2}+y$$ is bijective or not.

Attempt:
I check $F(x_1,y_1)$ and $F(x_2,y_2)$ 
and ends up in 
$$(x_1+y_1)^2-3x_1-y_1=(x_2+y_2)^2-3x_2-y_2$$
Now how to show $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$?
How one can show it is surjective?

Comment: What is the domain and the range?

Comment: Its  function from cartesian product of natural to natural

Comment: Find $x_1$ in terms of $y_1$, $x_2$, $y_2$.  Replace all $x_1$ in the equation.  Find $y_1$ in terms of $x_2$ and $y_2$.  Find back $x_1$ on the same dependencies by replacing every occurrence of $y_1$.  Does $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$ ?

Comment: It is too cumbersome exercise to find x1 in terms of y1,x2 and y2 and next are also so please tell another approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverting the Cantor pairing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222709/inverting-the-cantor-pairing-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function)

This is a table of $M_{i,j} = F(i,j)$ where $1 \le i,j \le 6$.

$$M = \left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
    1 &  3 &  6 & 10 & 15 & 21 \\
    2 &  5 &  9 & 14 & 20 & 27 \\
    4 &  8 & 13 & 19 & 26 & 34 \\
    7 & 12 & 18 & 25 & 33 & 42 \\
   11 & 17 & 24 & 32 & 41 & 51\\
   16 & 23 & 31 & 40 & 50 & 61 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

We can show that the "up-one over-one" diagonal elements increase by $1$ by computing

$$F(i-1,j+1)-F(i,j) = 1$$

Then the sequence $F(n,1), F(n-1,2),F(n-2,3), \dots, F(1,n)$ is an arithmetic sequence with common difference $1$.

To continue this sequence starting at the next diagonal, we see that

$$F(n+1,1) - F(1,n) = 1 $$

Since $F(1,1)=1$, it follows that $F$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as

$(x_1+y_1)^2-(x_2+y_2)^2+3(x_2-x_1)+(y_2-y_1)=0$
Now suppose, $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $y_1 \neq y_2$.

What can you say about the expression i.e., can it be $0$?
Remember $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: how you can tell that it is zero if x1=x2 and y1=y2 only? there might be other solutions.

Comment: No, I made a mistake. It's maybe hard to conclude from this.

Answer (score 0):

Its not even injective, since $F(2,0) = 0 = F(1,0)$

Comment: I'm assuming that $0$ is not supposed to be a natural number in this case and he is not aware that there is a confusion about that.

Comment: @stevengregory The OP forgot to mention it in the question, it is made clear only in the comments. I am personally unclear, what to do in this case.

Comment: Some people say that the set of natural numbers is $\{0,1,2, \dots\}$ and some say $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. In the case of this problem, I am pretty sure that $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. So $F(2,0)$ and $F(1,0)$ are not included and their values are of no concern to your problem.